How to save values to a CSV file in exponent in python
For a project in Python i have to read float values from an excel file and save it as exponential values in a CSV file by using Pandas. When i print the values, they are shown as exponent, but when i open the CSV file afterwards, i get only float values. How to save them as exponential values?
    Datas = pd.read_excel(Dateiname_Excel, sheet_name = "Tabelle1", header=0)
    print (Datas)

    pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.1E}'.format)
    print (Datas)

    Datas_2 = Datas.astype(float, '{:.1E}'.format)
    Datas_2["Pos"] = Datas_2["Pos"].astype(int)

    Datas_2.to_csv(Dateiname_CSV, index = None, header = HeaderList)
    print (Datas_2)

    CSV_File.close()


Do you have an example of input values?

[ask] and [mre]

The formatting you applied with
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.1E}'.format) is for display purposes only and does not affect how data is written to files.
I try to correct it for you
enter code here
   import pandas as pd
   Datas = pd.read_excel(Dateiname_Excel, sheet_name="Tabelle1", header=0)
   Datas_2 = Datas.copy()
   for col in Datas_2.select_dtypes(include=['float']):
      Datas_2[col] = Datas_2[col].apply(lambda x: f'{x:.1E}')
   if 'Pos' in Datas_2.columns:
      Datas_2["Pos"] = Datas_2["Pos"].astype(int)
   Datas_2.to_csv(Dateiname_CSV, index=None, header=HeaderList)
   print(Datas_2)
   
  


Decide which columns have to be converted and make a list of their names.
Then:
import pandas as pd

Dateiname_Excel = "foo.xlsx"
Dateiname_CSV = "foo.csv"
Sheet = "Tabelle1"
Columns = ["ColA", "ColB"] # list of columns to be converted

def fmt(s: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    try:
        return s.apply(lambda x: f"{x:.1E}")
    except Exception:
        pass
    return s

df = pd.read_excel(Dateiname_Excel, sheet_name=Sheet)
df[Columns] = df[Columns].apply(fmt)
df.to_csv(Dateiname_CSV, index=False)


You just need to use the parameter float_format in to_csv():
df.to_csv("test_sn.csv", float_format='{:.4E}'.format)


This will work for cell values that have a decimal fraction. However, in reality it's common for cell values to be presented as an integer when the intent is that it should be fractional - i.e., a column might contain 99 and 99.9. The float_format specification would only cause 99.9 to be formatted and not 99

@SIGHUP On my computer, it also works with 99 which become 9.9000E+01 in the csv file.

It will not work if an entire column is comprised solely of integers. The apparent intention in the OP is that all columns except "Pos" should be reformatted

@SIGHUP If I force one column to be integer, yes obviously you are correct. But I think that I answer the OP question though it is possible that I may be wrong!

With my solution, the integer column will stay integer if it is what the OP wants and if the OP wants to have it with exponent, just need to transform the column into float with .astype(float). So it is a quick and easy solution.
